# Why can I not import arabic csv file into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have an arabic `.csv` file on my pc, and I want to import that file into SQL Server, but when I import it, I get this error:

> Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

What happened?

Comment: what is the column data type of the sql server? also are you sure there is not more data in the file than the column length allows ?

Comment: can you please provide table structure? If you assign nvarchar(MAX) datatype, then may be conversion will happen successfully.

Comment: @SomnathKadam i'm use the varchar field datatype

Comment: Well here is your problem, to store Arabic in sql server you need `NVARCHAR` or `NCHAR` data types so you can store the uni-code characters.

Comment: @M.Ali ok,please wait to test that.

Comment: @M.Ali I'm change the field data type to nvarchar(max) but in the csv file has a 1 million record,and so 1 record import!

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi can you provide any sample data that could have been coverted during the process?

Comment: @SomnathKadam your solution is work ,please post your answer to i vote up you.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing data other than English language like arabic, hindi etc, we need nvarchar(MAX) or nchar(MAX), instead of varchar(MAX).

Below example shows difference between varchar and nvarchar

```
Create table tab (remark varchar(MAX)  );
insert into tab values('This is test');

Create table tab_arabic (remark nvarchar(MAX)  );
insert into tab_arabic values(N'هذا هو الاختبار');
```

Comment: This will also fail unless you do `insert into tab_arabic values(N'هذا هو الاختبار');`